# Not able to generate iOS developer certificate

Tags: ios, certificate, code-signing, apple-developer

I am logging into my apple account there is no option coming regarding certificates or provisioning profiles please help me.

Here with attached screenshot of the window, I am able to see.

[image]

Comment: Have you paid for your membership and completed the tax and banking forms in itunesconnect?

Comment: your account is free, are you the paid member

Comment: But I read somewhere that $99 scheme etc is not required anymore

Comment: No , I am not a paid member

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik What to do?

Comment: @AashimaAnand If you enable the automatic signing in Xcode, the Xcode automatically creates the certificates and provisioning for you. With the free account, you can debug and test on the device. You cannot distribute or submit the app to the testers/users/AppStore. If you want to distribute the app, you need to purchase $99 Apple developer program.

Comment: Please take membership $99 than it will be show

Comment: @AashimaAnand - see this https://mobileroadie.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200091736-iOS-Developer-Account-Step-by-Step-Guide